# cannot see device anymore when connecting to PC via USB

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb, android-pc

Lately I'm experiencing this problem when connecting my LG G2 smartphone to the PC: I cannot see it anymore in explorer.
I can actually connect to it tru ADB and push/pull files no problem. Also ADB shell works, developer options / debug USB enabled.
In Windows registry / System I got a critical error event id 10110 - 10111 DriverFrameworks-UserMode each time I connect it to usb.

Drivers are installed, cable is ok, I tried on several PC and can't see it, also tried with Linux, same problem.

If I dmesg | grep usb I got these two errors:

```
<3>usb_bam_ipa_create_resources: Failed to create USB_PROD resource
<3>init: cannot find '/system/bin/usbdebug-manager', disabling 'usbdebug-manager'
```

I'm 100% sure is not a problem PC side, but smartphone side.
I've been repacking /system/app and system/framework app to slim down my system, but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

LG G2 KK modified stock rom, Dorimanx Kernel

Comment: It sounds like the drivers maybe corrupted. Try un-installing and then re-installing (If possible updated) drivers? You could also try toggling the different usb modes such as mtp , ptp, and others. Debloating did you un-install a system app that had `Mtp` in name?

Comment: drivers are ok, 100% sure about that. Changing to other modes doesn't do the trick. I'll try to remember what apps I've disabled. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.  Btw Linux gives me this dmesg 'usb 1-1.3: usbfs: process 954 (pool) did not claim interface 0 before use
usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci'

Comment: I learned something new android has a connection assistant for usb troubleshooting. This would be good with your linux machine: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device I do not know what process 954 is but something bad happened (obviously) and your linux machine reset high Speed usb for device number 6 (whatever device 6 is probably your android) which is pretty crazy to do in the middle of an operation. Is your data cable connecting your device to the linux machine old? Maybe try another chord.

Comment: What does the command `mtp-detect` return on your linux machine?

Comment: libmtp version: 1.1.13
    
    Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=1004 and PID=61f9) is a LG Electronics Inc. Android phone (ID2).
   Found 1 device(s):
   LG Electronics Inc.: Android phone (ID2) (1004:61f9) @ bus 1, dev 6
Attempting to connect device(s)
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device  
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt  
Unable to open raw device 0  
OK.

Comment: That failed anyway Linux: Try editing/adding udev rules. Here is a walk through under Linux: 

https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/0.4/concepts/mobile-android-detect/

Make sure the not folder all did not get removed when Debloating seach with a file explorer for `mtp` should look something `com.android.mtp` or `com.your_manufacturer.mtp`

What version of linux?

Comment: That didn't work either. I searched into the original image file I downloaded, there's no `mtp` system app. Btw, if I enter TWRP recovery and plug usb cable I see my device straight in explorer no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87405/discussion-between-ju-tutt-and-bo-lawson).